# MYSQL need AVERAGE from one table based on information from second table

Tags: mysql

I'm slowly teaching myself MySQL methods, and I'm having a tough time with this.  I haven't even been able to figure out HOW to Google the question.

I have the following two tables (I think my data is normalized, but suggestions welcome):

Table 1

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| rate_id  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| rate     | decimal(9,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| guess    | decimal(9,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date     | date         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| house_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date_mod | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table 2

```
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(64)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| beds            | int(2)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| baths           | int(2)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pets            | char(4)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pool            | char(4)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to populate `guess` with the average `rate` of all properties during the same `date` period, based on similar properties in table 2.  That is, for each `id`/`house_id`, I need all the houses that are similar (same beds, baths, view, etc.), and then the average of all the `rate`s on the same `date`s.

My biggest issue is that I don't understand how to reference a field in a second table based on the `id` selected.  This is what I'm starting with - just to see if I can get averages to return (I know this won't UPDATE the `guess` field).

```
SELECT AVG(t1.rate)
INNER JOIN t2 ON (t1.house_id = t2.id)
WHERE t2.beds = t2.beds
  AND t2.baths = t2.baths
  AND t2.pets = t2.pets
  AND t1.date = t1.date
  AND t1.house_id = 2;
```

Aside from the fact that the SQL command doesn't complete - I think it's obvious that my SQL knowledge is woefully inadequate - I think I'm just missing a more complex SQL method to identify the fields I'm looking for.  Can anybody help?

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with baby steps, like a book or tutorial

Comment: As for googling keywords, how about 'mysql' and 'average'?

Answer (score 0):

@Strawberry - appreciate the comments.  As it turns out, I already had AVG() working (I had already Googled it)

My problems were in two sets.  First, how does one get column values from one table to use to get keys for us on another table.  I didn't realize that you could use a nested `SELECT` statement to do this - although I still haven't convinced myself this is the most efficient way to do this.

Second, the average function was grouping all rates together into one average.  I was able to do a bit of manipulation to produce the output I was looking for, but ultimately, the `GROUP BY` function was able to provide me most of the functionality I needed.  Below is basically what I ended up with.

```
SELECT date, AVG(t1.rate) FROM rates  
JOIN houses ON (t1.house_id = t2.id)  
WHERE beds = (SELECT beds FROM t2 WHERE id = 2)  
  AND baths = (SELECT baths FROM t2 WHERE id = 2)  
  AND pets = (SELECT pets FROM t2 WHERE id = 2)  
GROUP BY date;
```

Thanks for commenting.